# Runtime model generation in Django or other languages

Tags: django

I'm asking this question for hearing about advice and having an idea about the possibility of this type work. Not asking for any code help, just advice, and a little leading would be helpful, if it is still the wrong place to ask this question, sorry about that.

I would like to build an application that lets users upload a CSV or excel file and generate a SQL table at the backend at that time and store data into the table. Then print the loaded data in UI.
I did it before in a terrible and messy way by using the `Create Table` query and `select` query for printing data. I believe you will think of me how a programmer can be so ridiculous if you see these codes. That's the reason I want to learn if there is a better and standard way to do the same thing or shouldn't do something like that at all? And how other companies do this type of works? You can advise different programming languages if there are any.

I read about documents Dynamic Models. I understand a little, but they don't advise to build in that way, so I don't know if it is worth going deep and put effort or not.

Comment: Why do you need to create a DB table? If the goal is to display data from a CSV then can you not just create a view that renders the contents of an uploaded CSV?

Comment: Because I would use that data in different places and also update/insert new data from the UI. I think it would fail after having millions of rows.

Comment: EAV is one pattern you could use, there are several Django packages that implement it. JSON fields could also be used to store any serialisable data. It's hard to comment without knowing what your desired outcome is: do you want to dynamically create forms/APIs/tables/validation/searches?

Comment: `do you want to dynamically create forms/APIs/tables/validation/searches?` Exactly. For example, instead of having a SalesTransaction Model during the development, the User will create a SalesTransaction model in Runtime and will continue to insert or delete data from that model. About Json; You mean can I store data in Json in a pre created model in a format like `[{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": 0,
  "ModelName": "SalesTransaction"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parent": 1,
  "Field1": "Value1",
  "Field2": "Value2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parent": 1,
  "Field1": "Value3",
  "Field2": "Value4"
}]`

Comment: Django EAV (2) may be a solution, it will allow you to dynamically create attributes/values and has utilities for creating forms from those attributes

Comment: I will check EAV. Thanks a lot. Meantime, what do you think about storing all data in JSON format in a field of a table? It will be a good idea in case of a lot of tables with a lot of fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227743/discussion-between-cem-and-iain-shelvington).